# How to get HtmlDocument after jquery changes? (HtmlAgilityPack)

Tags: c#, jquery, html-agility-pack

Is it possible to get HtmlDocument after jQuery changes? For example, get element by 'myId' after the next change.

The js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#myContainer").html("<div id='myId'></div>");
});
```

The C# code:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
...
doc.GetElementbyId("myId");
```

How?

Comment: I doubt the `HtmlDocument` is interpreting and internally executing the JavaScript code.  In this sense, jQuery doesn't "change" anything.  It's just code being delivered to the client.  In the case of most web browsers, they'll execute that code.  I don't know of any automated HTTP request/response libraries which do that, though.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do that using a mix of HtmlAgilityPack and [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. I think it's worth to take a look. You would load the html using
`WebBrowser` and you'd parse it with `HtmlDocument`.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET) Code Project article could be a good start point